# Organising MainActivity into classes

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively new to Android, especially with regard to creating larger projects. I tend to just add to the MainActivity, but it then becomes unwieldy very quickly, and I'd like to refactor/organise my code better.

Suppose I have a MainActivity performing an action someAction() initiated by user input through gestures and button clicks:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    public void someAction() {
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        someAction();
    }

    ...

    public void buttonClick(View view) {
        // called from res/layout: <Button android:onClick="buttonClick" ... />
        someAction();
    }

}
```

How can I split this into different classes/files, to keep files smaller? I would like to end up with something like this:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void someAction() {
    }
}
```

MyGestureDetection.java:

```
public class MyGestureDetection extends MainActivity implements
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        someAction();
    }
```

MyButtonHandler.java:

```
public class MyButtonHandler extends MainActivity {
    public void buttonClick(View view) {
        // called from res/layout: <Button android:onClick="buttonClick" ... />
        someAction();
    }
}
```

**Question 1 (general):** What is the right approach to use?

**Question 2 (concrete):** I've been able to split my code as above, and e.g. the MyGestureDetection class can see the someAction() method, so that's fine. However, it seems that the MyGestureDetection doesn't get instantiated. What do I need to do in MainActivity to make this work?

Comment: You don't need to extend all your classes with MainActivity.

Comment: The reason I did that is so that e.g. the MyGestureDetection class can use the someAction() method.

Comment: You can do that by sending the Activity as parameter in your `MyGestureDetection` constructor, like `public MyGestureDetection(Activity activity) { this.activity = new WeakReference<>(activity).get() }`. Then change `someAction()` to the method that you use in MainActivity.

Comment: Because when you extend MainActivity you just making another activity which use the `GestureDetector` interface.

Comment: OK, thanks - I think I have reading to do. This way of communication between classes is not that clear to me - see my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To not treat Activities like God objects, one should use one of the clean architectures ( MVP, VIPER, MVVM etc.. ) ...

For example, in MVP ( stands for Model - View - Presenter ) your View layer would be an activity ( or fragment, so you use Activity just as an lifecycle container ) which renders the screen and propagate all user interaction to the Presenter.. Presenter will then do your business logic and contact Model layer to retrieve information and data ...

You can find more useful information and tutorials to get you started on clean architectures.. For example [here](https://github.com/konmik/konmik.github.io/wiki/Introduction-to-Model-View-Presenter-on-Android)

Comment: OK, yes, that sounds good. Had a look at the link as well, and I get the ideal. However, I think my java knowledge is a bit too basic. Do you know of a super-simple example? Or another tutorial that spells out the details?